# User References : After Change Language (window 32bit): very slow

Tags: rendering, blender-internal-render-engine

I use 32bit window and blender OS 32bit, After changing the language, the program runs slowly, start the program after the last open,when using (64bit window with blender 64bit) is running normally, but when I use OS 32bit blender in window(32bit) very slow.

I don't know why, please help me

Thank you so much!

[image]

Comment: I'm confused. Is your OS 32 bit or 64 bit? Use a version of blender that matches your operating system.

Comment: OS 32 Bit is very slow

Comment: You can't use a 64 bit version of blender in a 32 bit OS. Likewise if your OS is 64 bit it makes no sense to use a 32 bit version.

Comment: I know, now i using OS 32bit(blender) with window(32bit), but after i changed language, it run very slow.